# Can Multiple Monitors be used on a GT 220?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an [nVidia GT 220 Graphics card](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_220_us.html), and considering hooking up dual monitors.

I currently use one on the VGA port, but the card has an HDMI and DVI. Can i use more than one port on the card at once?

Comment: Did you manage to run two monitors on this card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This card should support two displays, but not three.  (I have not tested this particular card but this would be normal behavior for this generation of GeForce.)

Comment: Okay. I will likely borrow a friend's monitor to test it then. The card isn't as shiny and new as it used to be